# How to make NAME function work in VLOOKUP formulas for Excel 2010

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I have 3 sheets (ABC, DEF, GHI) where each sheet has 3 tables (TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3) and each table has 2 columns where 1st column consists of dates and 2nd column consists of data.

I defined "NAME"s for each table (ie. ABCTABLE1, ABCTABLE2, ABCTABLE3, DEFTABLE1, DEFTABLE2... etc.).

On another sheet, following 3 input cells are required to be filled by user (Sheet(B1), Table(B2) and Date(B3)). Let's assume they were filled by user as follows:

(B1): **DEF**
(B2): **TABLE2**
(B3): **05.01.2014**

I also have 2 more cells where:

(B4): shows concatenated info of (B1) and (B2) with the formula (**=B1&B2**)
(ie. "**DEFTABLE2**" in our example in order to find which of the defined NAMEs should be used to bring up data in cell (B5).

(B5): shows data result, with the formula (**=VLOOKUP(B3,B4,2,FALSE**)

Although (B5) is expected to go to table NAME ("DEFTABLE2") and find date (05.01.2014) and choose 2nd column with data result of "65", it gives an error #N/A.

If I just enter manually the NAME as (=VLOOKUP(B3,**DEFTABLE2**,2,FALSE) by choosing from the defined NAMEs, data is coming properly. But if I try to pick that from a cell (B4) which contains the NAME as mentioned, it doesn't work. Any workarounds would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=INDIRECT(B4)` formula. It will return reference link from its text name.